# How to display AlertDialog in Flet

Tags: python, flet

in the opposite code, I want to display an AlertDialog, but I was having problems. Can anyone help me? I can also send the complete code if needed

```
import flet as ft
class Task(ft.UserControl):
    def __init__(self, task_name, task_status_change, task_delete):
        super().__init__()
        self.completed = False
        self.task_name = task_name
        self.task_status_change = task_status_change
        self.task_delete = task_delete
        ...
    def build(self):
        ...
class TodoApp(ft.UserControl):
    def build(self):
        return ft.Column(
            controls=[
                ft.Row(
                    [
                        ft.ElevatedButton(text="button",on_click=self.route_change),
                    ],
                    alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.SPACE_BETWEEN,
                ),
            ],
        )
    async def route_change(self, e):

        dlg_modal = ft.AlertDialog(
            title=ft.Text("login"),
            content=ft.Text("asasasas"),
            actions=[
                ft.TextButton("Yes"),
                ft.TextButton("No"),
            ],
            actions_alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.END,
        )
        self.dialog = dlg_modal
        dlg_modal.open = True
        self.update()
async def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.horizontal_alignment = ft.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER
    page.scroll = ft.ScrollMode.ADAPTIVE
    await page.add_async(TodoApp())
ft.app(main)
```

When I click on the button, nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

I think the error comes from the `TodoApp.route_change` function.
Just after you store the AlertDialog in the `dlg_modal` variable, simply call `await e.page.show_dialog_async(dlg_modal)`. (comment/remove the remaining code below)

```
async def route_change(self, e):
   dlg_modal = ft.AlertDialog(
        title=ft.Text("login"),
        content=ft.Text("asasasas"),
        actions=[
            ft.TextButton("Yes"),
            ft.TextButton("No"),
        ],
        actions_alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.END,
    )
   await e.page.show_dialog_async(dlg_modal)
```

Please share the complete code if the above suggestion doesn't work.